# Basic doubt about wavy curve method

Tags: inequality, inverse-function

I need to find the domain of $$\sin^\text{-1}\left(\dfrac{1}{|x^2-1|}\right)$$
Hence,
$$-1 \le \dfrac{1}{|x^2-1|} \le 1 \\ \implies \dfrac{1-|x^2-1|}{|x^2-1|} \le 0 $$

Then I made two cases, first that $x^2-1\ge 0$ or $ -1\ge x\ge 1$  and second that, $-1\le x\le 1$

Skipping to the result,
$x \in (-\infty, -\sqrt2) \cup (\sqrt2,\infty)$
 However, $x=0$ also satisfies this inequality.
So, am I forgetting something?

Is it just a coincidence here or should I check all the critical points everytime?

Or if not, then when?

Comment: The case $-1\le x\le 1$ reduces to $-x^2\ge 0$, which you mistakenly rejected. In fact this inequality is satisfied by $x=0$.

Comment: Oh no... I didn't reject that.. I opened the mod with a negative sign, but forgot to do that in denominator.. but even if I do that, the answer is same. I know that it's not necessary because the denominator is always positive, but would it change the answer (well yeah, I saw that, but still..)

Comment: Your comment is incomprehensible, from start to finish!

Comment: Yeah. Sorry for that. (>ლ). It was like I was talking to myself. See my comment on the top answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{|x^2-1|} \le 1 \implies |x^2-1| \ge 1 \implies x^2-1 \ge 1 ....(1)~or~ x^2-1\le -1...(2).$$
From (1), we get: $x^2 \ge 2 \implies x \le -\sqrt{2}~or~ x \ge \sqrt{2}$.....(3)

From (2), we get $x^2 \le 0 \implies x=0 $......(4)

The final solution is $x\in (-\infty,-\sqrt{2}] \cup [\sqrt{2}, \infty) \cup \{0\}$

**OP's way**
You can only write $$\frac{1}{|x^2-1|} \le 1 \implies \frac{1-|x^2-1|}{|x^2-1|} \le 0$$ there are two cases
$$Case (1):~ \text{when}~ x^2 > 1 \implies x <- 1~or~ x>1....(A)$$ Then
we get: $$\frac{x^2-2}{x^2-1}\ge 0 \implies (x^-2)(x^2-1) \ge 0 \implies (x+\sqrt{2})(x-\sqrt{2})(x+1)(x-1) \ge 0 \implies x \in (-\infty, -\sqrt{2}) \cup (-1,1) \cup [\sqrt{2}, \infty)....(B)$$
In this case (1), the solution is the overlap of (A) and (B) which is
$$x \in (-\infty, -\sqrt{2}] \cup [\sqrt{2}, \infty)....(C)$$

$$Case (2): x^2 <1 \implies  -1<x <1....(D)$$ $$\implies \frac{x^2}{1-x^2}\le 0 \implies x^2(x^2-1) \ge 0 \implies (x+1) x^2 (x-1) \ge 0 \implies x=0, x\in (-\infty, -1) \cup (1, \infty).....(E)$$
The overlap of (D) and (E) is just $x=0$

Finally, the solution comes from (C) where $\{0\}$ has to be included.

Comment: What if for $x \in [-1,1] $ I do $$ \dfrac{1+(x^2-1)}{-(x^2-1)}\le 0$$ $$ \dfrac{x^2}{x^2-1}\ge 0$$ that gives $x \in (-\infty,-1] \cup [1,\infty)$

Comment: @AshWhole You may see my edit for you.

Comment: yeah that's exactly my question. By wavy curve, we don't get 0 as a solution. But it clearly is, if we plug it into the inequality. So, is necessary to check for all critical points/roots especially of even powers, as in, this is a flaw in the method. Or it was a coincidence in this case? Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

you effectively have:
$$\frac{1}{|x^2-1|}\le1$$
now if we flip this over that leads to:
$$|x^2-1|\ge1$$
and this leads to the two regions bounded in the way that you said. Notice that this gives you two domains for which the function is continuous, and $0$ is the single point that works (the function is not continuous around this point as it is a singularity) so if you want the domain where the function is continuous then you would not include it

Comment: But cross multiplying (or multiplying/dividing both sides) has some restrictions , whether the number is positive or negative. In this case it's positive, won't it alter the inequality if it was negative?

Comment: I suppose the function is continuous at 0? (Only the mod). I don't know if you're talking about the whole inequality or just the modulus function. Pardon me, my brain is tired now.